# How do I pass the boolean value from child component to parent component so that I can use that value to enable/disable the sibling child component?

Tags: angular, typescript, eventemitter, angular-event-emitter

I have this parent component

-*person.component.html*

```
<div>
    <main>
        <address-list (addressPresent)="setPersonInfo($event)"></address-list>
        <company-list *ngIf="personInfo"></company-list>
    </main>
</div>
```

-*address-list.component.ts*

```
addressExists: boolean;
@Output() addressPresent: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

updateAddress(value: boolean) {
    this.addressPresent.emit(value);
}

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.data();
}

data(): void {
    ...
    ...
    this.personService.getPersonInfo(this.personId).subscribe((res => {
       ...
       this.updateAddress(res.body.personInfo);
       ...
    }))
}
```

-*person.component.ts*

```
personInfo: boolean;

setPersonInfo(value: boolean): void {
    this.personInfo = value;
}
```

How do I pass the boolean value from `address-list` component to `person` component so that I can use it to enable or disable the `company-list` component?

Implementation that I have done returns `undefined` value for `addressExists` variable when I log it inside `ngOnInit()`.

Comment: Did you console log `res.body.personInfo` before emitting it from `updateAddress`? Is it undefined?

Comment: Yes I did. It's not undefined.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where you're setting addressExists.  You define it as a boolean at the top, but don't set it to anything.  So it will be undefined.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a service, one suggestion would be to just have an observable in the service that handles the subscription. Like so:

*person.service.ts:*

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PersonService {

  private personSelectedSource: Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>();
  personSelected$ = this.personSelectedSource.asObservable();

  constructor() { }

  setPersonSelected(selected: boolean) {
    this.personSelectedSource.next(selected);
  }

}
```

*address-list.component.ts:*

```
constructer(private personService: PersonService) { }

// This would be your method that is called when a person/address is selected
selectPerson(person: any) {
  this.personService.setPersonSelected(person == null ? false : true);
}
```

*person.component.ts:*

```
constructor(private personService: PersonService) { }

personInfo: boolean = false;

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.personService.personSelected$.subscribe(selected => {
    this.personInfo = selected;
  });
}
```